# Drawing two lines to connect 2 couple button with c#

Tags: c#, drawing

I have four buttons, now I want to draw button1 with button 2, button 3 with button 4 but after size the window the line is disappear. Please tell me how to do.

Comment: can you share some code showing us what you are trying to do?

Comment: You need to draw in the Paint event using the e.Graphics parameter!